# TFS 2017 Team Notification Available Roles

Tags: tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

I am trying to setup team notifications for work item changes using Role based alert delivery in on-premises TFS 2017. In the *Deliver to Specific team members* dropdown I can select Assigned To, Previous Assignee, Current Assignee, but in our template we have Owner field that I also want to have in the dropdown like Owner, Previous Owner, Current Owner.

Is there any process customization to apply to make these roles appended to the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Roles field can not be customized. I have submitted a user voice at website below, you can vote it:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34325335-customize-tfs-team-notification-available-roles